# SurfaceView background slows down onDraw 20-30 ms

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, android-canvas

I set my background image up in surfaceCreated() using this code:

```
    Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.untitled);
    float heightScale = ((float)background.getHeight())/(float)this.getHeight();
    float widthScale = (float)background.getWidth()/(float)this.getWidth();
    float scale = heightScale > widthScale ? widthScale : heightScale;
    int newWidth = Math.round((float)background.getWidth()/scale);
    int newHeight = Math.round((float)background.getHeight()/scale);
    scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Scaled being a protected bitmap. During the onDraw() function, I have this:

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null); // draw the background
```

Which slows down my drawing by 20-30 ms compared to using this:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.Black);
```

Is there any way around this?  Speeding up the background onDraw function? I noticed that if I do not set the background, the app will not clear the sprites I drew.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Here's how you do it:

You create a layout and set the layout as the content view.  Then add the surfaceview to the layout, then set the surface view pixel format to transparent like so:

```
    panel = new Panel(this, getNewHandler());   
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.panellinear)).addView(panel);
    SurfaceHolder p;
    panel.setZOrderOnTop(true);    // necessary
    p = panel.getHolder();
    p.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT)
```

(Panel for me is something that extends SurfaceView)